# Run command on Cloud Foundry in it's own container

Tags: cloud-foundry

As you can see on the official doc of Cloud Foundry

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html

A task is an application or script whose code is included as part of a deployed application, but runs independently in its own container.

I'd like to know if there's a way to run command and manipulate files directly on the main container of an application without using a SSH connection or the manifest file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Tasks run in their own container, so they cannot affect other running tasks or running application instances.  That's the designed behavior.

If you need to make changes to your application, you should look at one of the following:

- Use a `.profile` script.  This will let you execute operations prior to your application starting up.  It runs for every application instance that is started (I do not believe it runs for tasks) so the operation will be consistently applied.

  While not recommended, you can technically background a task through the `.profile` script that will continue running for the duration of your app.  This is not recommended because there is no monitoring of this script and if it crashes it won't cause your app container to restart.
- Integrate with your buildpack.  Some buildpack's like the PHP buildpack provide hooks for you to integrate and add behavior to staging.  For other buildpacks, you can fork the buildpack and make it do whatever you want.  This includes changing the command that's returned by the buildpack which tells the platform how to execute your droplet and ultimately what runs in the container.

You can technically modify a running app instance with `cf ssh`, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's something you should really only do for troubleshooting or maybe testing.  Definitely not production apps.  If you feel like you *need* to modify a running app instance for some reason, I'd suggest looking at the reasons why and look for alternative ways of accomplishing your goals.